# How to build ancestor tree without using ancestor-or-self::*

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

I need to get the path to a number of values, however then Xquery environment I'm working in doesn't support this syntax 
`for $ancestor in $datum/ancestor-or-self::*` specifically this axis is causing problems `ancestor-or-self::*`. can't seem to figure this out. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of the `ancestor*` axes, you could either recursively climb the `parent` axis, or use the `root()` function to retrieve the document node and then descend along the `child` or `descendant` axis.